# ResourceTool : to recover a jpg with ResourceNode [velocity]

Tags: java, velocity

During my searching, I would like a piece of advice about the following situation :

the guy, on my website, choose a parcel to send, when he validates the choice, some carriers appear as results. Now some carriers have different offers with different logos located in a special directory.

Now the business logic I would like to use is :

If in the directory I find the peculiar logo corresponding to the special offer, I will take the logo to display It in the web page with the special offer.

I choose to do this work with the `ResourceTool` from  `Velocity`

I have to implement 2 methods `getLogo()` and `getLabel()`.

The `getLogo()` will look for the special logo.

I think to use this method to recover the object :

```
public static ResourceNode getResource(Context context, ResourceType resourceType, String...keys) {
    try {
        if (null != ResourcesTool.instance) {
            ResourceNode resource = ResourcesTool.instance.getResourceSet(context, resourceType);
            if (null != resource) {
                Deque < String > keyDeque = new ArrayDeque < > ();
                for (String key: keys) {
                    keyDeque.add(key);
                }
                return (ResourceNode) resource.sub(keyDeque);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        BoxtaleLogger.debug("[ResourcesTool.getResource] error: ", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now I am searching a example to merely use this method to recover the different .jpg

question 2 : I don't understand what is the meaningful of `Context context` in this method ?

Then the resourceType is an enum either a String or a picture (the logo in fact)

Answer (score 0):

All right I found It :

```
 public String getLogo(ResourceNode node){

  //readable variables
  String ope_code = (String)((Instance)get("operateur")).get("ope_code");
  String paysDest = ((Instance)db.getEntity("tab_pays").fetch((Integer) get("pz_id"))).get("pz_iso");

  String path = node.get(ope_code+"_"+get("srv_code")+"_"+paysDest+".png");

  if (path=null){
      path = node.get(ope_code+"_"+get("srv_code")+".png");
      if (path=null){     
        path = node.get(ope_code+".png");
      }
  }
  return path ;
```

}

Now I am testing the method, I will tell you after.